# how to highlight First Match in jquery auto complete

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete

How can I show first match selected in autocomplete while typeing.

example: my list has

[image]

When I type "Texas" list shows starting "Texas..." rest will be on up.

Is it possible to do with Jquery?

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-4 ">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InstitutionName, new { @class = " SPE-Formcontrol section_detail-font-14", Name = "InstitutionName" })</div>

$("#InstitutionName").autocomplete(
{
    search: function () { },
  
    source: function (request, response)
    {
        var UniversityName = $("#InstitutionName").val();
        
        var formData = { UniversityName: UniversityName };
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "GetInstitutionNamesAutoPoplate",
            dataType: "json",
            data: formData,
            success: function (data)
            {
                   
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        // if ('console' in window) console.log(item);
                        return {
                            value: item
                        }
                    }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    select: function (event, ui)
    {
        var test = ui.item ? ui.item.id : 0;
        if (test > 0)
        {
            alert(test);
        }
    }
});
```

Edit:
anyone has clue for this?